# DB solution for user activity feed

Tags: mongodb, redis, nosql

I am wokring on a project where user activity feed generation is needed. If user A follows user B and user B does some activity user A see it on his homepage.

Now I am looking for a DB solution for persisting user feed. Once user B commits some action all users who follow user B will receive a record. I think saving a mongodb document for a user with a list of object references will be better than saving a document for each feed record.

On the other hand, there will be many writes and even more reads and mongodb has a lock on a collection. Maybe this might be a problem. Or maybe Redis could be used for this. And redis having something with concurrency. I am not much experienced in both.

The summary question is what would be better to use for this task: Mongo, Redis or something else?

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like the database platform has not been selected yet? (Otherwise, upon a first reading, it initially sounded like you had an existing database and wanted some kind of data-change event notification, like triggers or something.) If this is in the early analysis stage, and the actual database technology has not been dictated to you (lucky you), then I would flesh out the overall architecture/design (and requirements) before committing to a specific database technology (and fwiw, Mongo and Redis are quite different: one is an in-memory cache, the other is a persistent store.)

Comment: what programming language will you use?

Comment: @michael_n We are using SOA aproach. yes, database is not selected for feeds service. The task is to do precalculation of user feeds. The amount of relationships may be quite big. Think of social network.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

see the blogpost: http://www.waistcode.net/blog/mongodb-newsfeed-schema-design-for-entexis
which exactly describes what you're looking for. IMHO: it's really elegant.

I was pointed to that blogpost through a related question ( [MongoDB database schema design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918921/mongodb-database-schema-design/10923080#10923080) )  a couple of days ago.

hth.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to evaluate [neo4j](http://neo4j.org/). It was created for many of the same use cases you're describing.

Comment: Graph-based Db's really shine when calculating stuff related to 'friends of friends', i.e: traversing more than 1 edge in a graph. That doens't seem to be the case here

Answer (score 2):

[Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) is a proven choice for self-hosting activity feeds although it is typically considered complex to run and operate.

Nowadays there are 3rd party / hosted options such as [GetStream.io](https://getstream.io) and [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/).