# how mongo query include " or " use index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

this is a question about how to create efficient indexes when query have "or". Without “or” ,I know how to create efficient index.

This is my query.

```
db.collection.find({
    'msg.sendTime':{$gt:1},
    'msg.msgType':{$in:["chat","g_card"]},
     $or:[{'msg.recvId':{$in:['xm80049258']}},{'msg.userId':'xm80049258'}],
     $orderby:{'msg.sendTime':-1}})
```

After reading some article, I create two single index on msg.recvId and msg.userId, and this make sense.

1. I want to know when mongodb execute "or", Is it divides all documents at very first ,then use msg.sendTime and msg.msgType ?
2. How to create  efficient indexes in this case?  Should I create indexes (msg.sendTime:1,msg.msgType:1,msg.recvId:1) and 
   (msg.sendTime:1,msg.msgType:1,msg.userId:1)

Thanks very much.

Comment: Take a look at [.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) and then take a look at its result for your query (and tweak it to see how explaination is changing)

Comment: I did this. But I want to know the procedure how mongo analysis the query include 'or' , not to find the proper indexes for this query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323102/mongodb-or-sort-index-how-to-avoid-sorting-in-memory/43360707#43360707 and https://blog.mlab.com/2012/06/cardinal-ins/ OrderBy happens in the end always for any DB.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @lovegupta .I will try tomorrow ,:)

Comment: find another thing: [Index Intersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/index-intersection/#previous-versions) . share with you.

Answer (score 2):

Paraphrasing from [$or Clauses and Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-clauses-and-indexes):

> When evaluating the clauses in the $or expression, MongoDB either performs a collection scan or, if all the clauses are supported by indexes, MongoDB performs index scans. That is, for MongoDB to use indexes to evaluate an $or expression, all the clauses in the $or expression must be supported by indexes.

Also from [Indexing Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/):

> Generally, MongoDB only uses one index to fulfill most queries. However, each clause of an $or query may use a different index

What those paragraph mean for `$or` queries are:

- In a `find()` query, **only one index can be used**. Therefore it's best to create an index that aligns with the fields in your query. Otherwise, MongoDB will do a collection scan.
- Except when the query is an `$or` query, where MongoDB can use **one index per `$or` term**
- In combination, **if you have `$or` in your query, it's best to put the `$or` term as the top-level term, and create an index for each term separately**

So to answer your question:

> I want to know when mongodb execute "or", Is it divides all documents at very first ,then use msg.sendTime and msg.msgType ?

If your query has a top-level `$or` clause, MongoDB can use one index per clause. Otherwise, it will do a collection scan, or a semi-collection scan. For example, if you have an index:

```
db.collection.createIndex({a: 1, b: 1})
```

There are two general type of query you can create:

#### 1. `$or` NOT on the top level of the query

This query can use the index, but will not be performant:

```
db.collection.find({a: 1, $or: [{b: 1}, {b: 2}]})
```

since the `explain()` output of the query is:

```
> db.collection.explain().find({a: 1, $or: [{b: 1}, {b: 2}]})
{
"queryPlanner": {
...
        "indexBounds": {
        "a": [
            "[1.0, 1.0]"
        ],
        "b": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
        ]
...
```

Note that the query planner cannot use the proper boundary for the `b` field, where it is doing a semi-collection scan (since it's searching for `b` from `MinKey` to `MaxKey`, i.e. everything). The query planner result above is basically saying: **"Find documents where `a = 1`, and scan all of them for `b` having value of `1` or `2`"**

#### 2. `$or` on the top level of the query

However, pulling the `$or` clause to the top-level:

```
db.collection.find({$or: [{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 1, b: 2}]})
```

will result in this query plan:

```
> db.test.explain().find({$or: [{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 1, b: 2}]})
{
"queryPlanner": {
...
    "winningPlan": {
    "stage": "SUBPLAN",
...
        "inputStages": [
            {
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
...
            "indexBounds": {
                "a": [
                "[1.0, 1.0]"
                ],
                "b": [
                "[1.0, 1.0]"
                ]
            }
            },
            {
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
...
            "indexBounds": {
                "a": [
                "[1.0, 1.0]"
                ],
                "b": [
                "[2.0, 2.0]"
                ]
```

Note that each term of the `$or` is treated as a separate query, each with a tight boundary. As such, the query plan above is saying: **"Find documents where `a = 1, b = 1` or `a = 1, b = 2`"**. As you can imagine, this query will be much more performant compared to the earlier query.

For your second question:

> How to create efficient indexes in this case? Should I create indexes (msg.sendTime:1,msg.msgType:1,msg.recvId:1) and (msg.sendTime:1,msg.msgType:1,msg.userId:1)

As explained above, you need to combine the proper query with the proper index to achieve the best result. The two indexes you proposed will be able to be used by MongoDB and will work best if you rearrange your query to have the `$or` in the top-level of your query.

I encourage you to understand the `explain()` output of MongoDB, since it's the best tool to find out if your queries are using the proper indexes or not.

Relevant resources that you may find useful are:

- [Explain Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/)
- [Create Indexes to Support Your Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/)
- [Indexing Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/)